# ogr2ogr, force DATE cast on a SQL request

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, date, null

I am trying to complete column null values on a .shp file with one default value. My column has a DATE type.

Files schema : "COLUMN_NAME TYPE(SIZE)"

- Input (with null values) :

  ```
  CLICHE VARCHAR(80) | DATE DATE(10) | HEURE_TU VARCHAR(80)
  ```
- Output (with defautl value) :

  ```
  CLICHE VARCHAR(80) | DATE_PVA DATE(10) | HEURE_TU VARCHAR(80)
  ```

I tried:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT geometry, CLICHE, CASE WHEN DATE IS NULL THEN '2012-01-01' ELSE DATE END as DATE_PVA, HEURE_TU FROM 'my_table'" outputfile.shp inputfile.shp
```

But I get a file with a VARCHAR(80) typed DATE_PVA column.

So I tried:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT geometry, CLICHE, CAST((CASE WHEN DATE IS NULL THEN '2012-01-01' ELSE DATE END) as DATE) as DATE_PVA, HEURE_TU FROM 'my_table'" outputfile.shp inputfile.shp
```

But I get a output file with a INT(9) type DATE_PVA column.

I am pretty sure that the 'aaaa-mm-dd' format is the good one, however I have also tried to modify date format '01-01-2012' and '01/01/2012'. No better results...

So I do not know what I can do. I need a command line solution to be able to run it in a script. However, I can try an other solution than ogr2ogr if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both shapefiles and SQLite have some oddities in handling times. It may be possible to do what you want by doing a conversion from one shapefile into another. However, myself I would first convert the shapefile into Spatialite database and update time field with SQL afterwards. Another option is to update your shapefile in place.

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "update inputfile set date=
'2016/10/10' where date is null" inputfile.shp
```

Comment: Ok it is find, thank you! I did not know ogrinfo... It is so simple with this solution.